# Javascript function not being called, function may be dead?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I'm trying to call a js function when a button is clicked in html, but it won't run. The button is being clicked, because I tested a prompt and it showed up, but when we put a function there it wont run...

```
function NextLesson(){
prompt("myprompt");
document.getElementById("Kek23").innerHTML = <c:outvalue= "${lesson.GetNextLesson()}"/>";}
```

Then I call the method in a button

```
<p style="font-size: 4em" id ="Kek23"></p>
<button onclick = "NextLesson();" value = "Next"/>
```

We've found that when a function gives an error, javascript declares the entire function as dead, but I don't know the error

Comment: Are you missing the closing `}` in your actual code, or did you just forget to copy it with the rest of the function?

Comment: `<c:outvalue= "${lesson.GetNextLesson()}"/>";` - what template system or engine is this?

Comment: Where are you declaring your function?  Everything works as you have it, see this js fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hjfmzwn6/

Comment: @jonhopkins oops, Ill fix that, it's in our actual code, I just didn't copy it

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher seems JSP code to me ... ?

Comment: You've also got unmatched quotes around your JSP `<c:out>`, and you need a space between out and value in your `<c:out>`.

Comment: I think I figured it out... I had some text, and used a "\n" and it wanted to move the text to the function for some reason. It's working now though!

Answer (score 2):

This works:
You had a couple syntax issues that was killing your function- including not completely wrapping your innerHTML content in quotes - and your Button element was not using the correct syntax.

```
<p style="font-size: 4em" id ="Kek23"></p>
<button onclick = "NextLesson();" value = "Next">Next</button>

<script>
function NextLesson(){
prompt("myprompt");
document.getElementById("Kek23").innerHTML = "<c:out value= ${lesson.GetNextLesson()}/>"
};
</script>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8ff3tomx/1/)

Comment: Did not even see that - thank you. I have corrected the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Errors corrected in the 2nd line of function:

```
function NextLesson(){
    prompt("myprompt");
    document.getElementById("Kek23").innerHTML = "<c:out value= '${lesson.GetNextLesson()}'/>";
}
```